# Is it possible to extract elements from google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, extract, feature-extraction

I want to make my final year project and for my idea I'd need the 3d buildings from google maps extracted somehow. Does google maps support this? Is it achievable ? I couldn't find anything really relevant on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason why you didn't find anything related to Google Maps is that the 3D information belongs to Google Earth. Google Maps/Earth API doesn't support this directly as far as I know.

The link below describes a process to get the information, I didn't test it and it's too complex and not mine to repeat here but basically "the only way to obtain this geometry is to capture it from the systems graphics engines (directX or opengl)." :
http://zachsoflin.com/blog/2012/03/01/extract-geometry-from-google-earth-to-mesh/

If you google ["Extracting 3d models from google Earth"](https://www.google.com/#q=extracting+3d+models+from+google+earth) you'll get more results.

Comment: On your Android google map api v2 with map_type set to road when you zoom into a large city like Detroit Michigan you can see the 3d buildings.  There's no way to get them out other than take a snapshot (bitmap)

Comment: So snapshots can be taken in-app with the API ? Or another method ?

Comment: If you just want a screen snapshot and not the 3D information:
"Just press the Volume Down and Power buttons at the same time, hold them for a second, and your phone will take a screenshot."
http://lifehacker.com/5994516/how-to-take-a-screenshot-on-android
or on Samsung phones the button combination is a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but have you tried 3D information from OpenStreetMap? I think some like http://www.osm-3d.org/map.htm have building height layers available, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://make2d.blogspot.com/2010/07/3d-models-from-google-earth.html) you can find a tutorial for extracting the 3D models from Google Earth.

Comment: Thank you, i was aware of that, but that process cannot be automatized under Android.